What is a good way to pass a PDF file from server component to client component in NextJs?
In my project, I'd like to fetch a PDf file from my .net backend and display it on the front end in nextJS.
To improve the user experience, I want to fetch data in the server component and pass the data to the client component as props.
The code is like:
const PDF = async ({params}:{params:{filename:string}}) => {

    const filename = params.filename;
    const response = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/api/users/1/pdfs?filename=${filename}`);
    const blob = await response.blob()
    const file = new File([blob], '123', { type: "application/pdf" });
    return (
        <PdfDrawingBoard fileBlob={file} pdfDrawingRecordsFromServer={pdfDrawingRecords} />
    )

The PdfDrawingBoard is  a client component.
But there is an error that I can not new FIle on server side?
I am considering some solutions like passing the PDF data in Buffer to the client component and then new file on the client side.
But I am wondering what is a good way to deal with this situation in NextJS.
Any suggestions would be appreciated!
